# XML-RPC with java

Tags: java, xml, rpc

I'm developing a server in XML-RPC  using Java , but when i compile it , i get this error

```
ServeurSomDiff.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addHandler(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer
                server.addHandler("SOMDIFF",new ServeurSomDiff ());
```

here 's my server :

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.*;
public class ServeurSomDiff {
public ServeurSomDiff (){ 
}
    public Hashtable sumAndDifference (int x, int y) {
        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
        result.put("somme", new Integer(x + y));
        result.put("difference", new Integer(x - y));
        return result;
      }
      public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
                   WebServer server = new WebServer(8000);
           server.addHandler("SOMDIFF",new ServeurSomDiff()); 
   server.start(); 
   System.out.println("Serveur lance sur http://localhost:8000/RPC2");  
       } catch (Exception exception) 
       {System.err.println("JavaServer: " + exception.toString());
             }
           }
        }
```

any ideas on how to fix this .
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the hadler mapping. From the webserver javadoc example:

```
   XmlRpcServer server = webServer.getXmlRpcServer();
   server.setConfig(config);
   server.setHandlerMapping(mapping);
```

Check http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/server/PropertyHandlerMapping.html for a possibly suitable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According the the [documentation](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/webserver/WebServer.html), there is no such method as "addHandler". Perhaps you meant a different class, or a different method?

Answer (score 0):

before compilation make sure the two xml-rpc jar files are in the same directory as the java files you've written. 
1- xmlrpc-1.2-b1
2- xmlrpc-1.2-b1-applet

here is a link
http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=2039
http://compsci.ca/v3/download.php?id=612

put this in same folder of server file and compile it by

java -cp .;lib* NameOfServer.java

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar problem in my project. The problem is that you are using the xmlrpc version 3 jar and using the code of version 2.
please download jar from following link, then your code should work.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlrpc201jar.htm